# UINavigationBar missplaced when MPMoviePlayerController exits fullscreen (ios 8 issue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app I am using MPMoviePlayerController to stream a video.The image of the navigationbar of the view before the player entering fullscreen and after when the player exits fullscreen are shown below.

> before fullscreen

[image: before]

> after fullscreen

[image: after]

the navigation bar is shifted up by 20 pixels.tried many things like setting the frame hiding and unhiding the frame etc.but no use.

HOw can I correct this?
1. Can I use uibarpositioningdelegate to correct this?If yes,How?

Please help,Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me you have used autolayout or autosizing for designing the view ?

Comment: I use autolayout and dynamically setting the height for some views as per the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Hide the navigation bar when entering fullscreen and display it again on unhide...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];     

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(mPExitFullScreen) 
    name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
    object:nil];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(mPEnterFullScreen) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];

}

- (void) mPExitFullScreen{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}

- (void)mPEnterFullScreen {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It helped 50%..Actually I have tried this before and the issue was that the mainscreen view was shifted up by 20 pixels every time when the movie player exits fullscreen.Resetting the view in viewDidAppear did the trick.[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];